# How to make ssh process not end when connection is lost

Tags: wifi, wicd-curses

I am trying to use wicd-curses to connect my raspberry pi to a wifi network, and for that I am accessing the pi through ssh having it connected to the wifi network created by my iphone. The thing is that as soon as I try to connect to the other wifi network, the connection with my iPhone's network is lost and I think that this terminates the process of connecting to the new network and it gets stuck. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
nohup mycommand &
```

The tool `nohup` is exactly made for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

[Mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) is what I've used. It is designed for exactly this use case. I use it on a laptop that switches networks all the time: public, VPN, wired, 4g. So long as your packets can get there, mosh will reconnect seamlessly.

Additionally, on the host itself, [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is incredibly useful for use cases where you need to start a long running process but might need to disconnect and want to check back on it later. I use this to stay logged into IRC on my pi, for example, so I can log IRC and rejoin the discussion at any point.